# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My java code passes  parameters as system current date-time and one hour before time in stored procedure call.

```
Date d = new Date();
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000); 
clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime())); 
clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', 'date'");
```

When I run the corresponding JSP page then the  `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: Date d = new Date();
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000); public String[][] getDbTable()
{ int i = 0;
  String [][]a = new String[3600][16];   
clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', 'date'"); 
clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime())); clstmt.execute();
rs = clstmt.getResultSet();                                      while (rs.next())
{for(int j=0; j<16; j++)
{
a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
}

i++;
} finally
{  closeConnection();
 } return a; }
THIS IS MY JAVA CODE.SP HAS 3 PARAMETERS AND LAST TWO ARE OF DATETIME TYPE.

Comment: @Fumu7 ABOVE MENTIONED IS MY CODE. I KNOW ITS BEING PRESENTED IN BAD WAY AS I'M NEW TO STACKOVERFLOW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) and then bind the value. That is swap the order of your statements like

```
// clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime())); 
clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge 'vs1_bag', 'd', 'date'"); 
clstmt.setDate("date", new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime()));
```

You get a `NullPointerException` because `clstmt` is `null` until you `prepareCall()`.

**Edit**

I think your syntax should be something like

```
clstmt = con.prepareCall("{call vcs_gauge('vs1_bag', 'd', ?) }"); 
clstmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime()));
```

**Edit 2**

Based on your additional details,

```
String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql); 
clstmt.setString(1, "vs1_bag");
clstmt.setString(2, df.format(d));
clstmt.setString(3, df.format(currentDate));
```

Comment: @EF when i do what you mentioned then Parameter date was not defined for stored procedure vcs_gauge exception is thrown.

Comment: @MES Edited. I wasn't paying attention to your sp call just the NPE.

Comment: @EF com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type varchar to datetime NOW THIS ERROR IS DISPALYED WHEN I DO AS YOU EDITED.

Comment: Post your StoredProc. Sounds like you need to format the column to a `String`. Basically, use `setString(1, dateFormat.format(currentDate.getTime()));` where dateFormat is the matching [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: @EF i can't change my SP.

Comment: @MES Read the second part of my comment again. In the stored proc it's a varchar, so you can't pass it a date.

Comment: MY CODE RUNS PROPERLY WHEN I CALL SP AS  clstmt = con.prepareCall("exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name='vs1_bag',@first_rec_time='2014-09-01 10:00:00',@last_rec_time='2014-09-01 11:00:00'") ;

Comment: @EF .I have checked my SP , last two columns are of datetime type only

Comment: @EF thanks for the effort.No exception are coming after doing as you said but empty table is displayed.No contents are fetched from the database.